# Why the shape of MOD02 image that was processed by gdalwarp is different with the image by the MCTK

Tags: python, coordinate-system, gdalwarp, modis

I am trying to project MOD021KM from Sinusoidal to WGS84 using gdalwarp with Python. The original image with HDF format was downloaded from NASA EOSDIS Reverb website. I used the code below. Moreover, I applied the MCTK in ENVI to project the image. The shape of two processed image is different.

```
gdalwarp -of GTIFF -r near -t_srs EPSG:4326 -ot Float32 HDF4_EOS:EOS_SWATH:"MOD021KM.A2017002.2050.005.2017003201059.hdf":MODIS_SWATH_Type_L1B:EV_250_Aggr1km_RefSB 2017002_F32.tif

0...10...20...30...40...50Warning 1: Metadata exceeding 32000 bytes cannot be written into GeoTIFF. Transferred to PAM instead.
```

The result is shown in the figure.
[image]

Why the shape of two image is different? How do I make the image which is processed by gdalwarp same shape as the image by the MCTK.

**UPDATE:**
The gdalinfo is following:

The image by gdalwarp:

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: 2017002_F32.tif
   2017002_F32.tif.aux.xml
Size is 4478, 1647
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
  DATUM["WGS_1984",
      SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
          AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
      AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
  PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
  UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
  AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
Origin = (-161.678555808543310,78.155197825739222)
Pixel Size = (0.013771295523432,-0.013771295523432)
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-161.6785558,  78.1551978) (161d40'42.80"W, 78d 9'18.71"N)
Lower Left  (-161.6785558,  55.4738741) (161d40'42.80"W, 55d28'25.95"N)
Upper Right (-100.0106945,  78.1551978) (100d 0'38.50"W, 78d 9'18.71"N)
Lower Right (-100.0106945,  55.4738741) (100d 0'38.50"W, 55d28'25.95"N)
Center      (-130.8446251,  66.8145360) (130d50'40.65"W, 66d48'52.33"N)
Band 1 Block=4478x1 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Gray
Description = Earth View 250M Aggregated 1km Reflective Solar Bands Scaled 
Integers
NoData Value=65535
Unit Type: none
```

The image by the MCTK:

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: 2017002_mctk.tif
Size is 2973, 2622
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
  DATUM["WGS_1984",
      SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
      AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
  PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
  UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
  AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
Origin = (-167.328659057617190,78.277236938476562)
Pixel Size = (0.023494699706713,-0.008966192967982)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  TIFFTAG_XRESOLUTION=1
  TIFFTAG_YRESOLUTION=1
Image Structure Metadata:
INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
  Upper Left  (-167.3286591,  78.2772369) (167d19'43.17"W, 78d16'38.05"N)
  Lower Left  (-167.3286591,  54.7678790) (167d19'43.17"W, 54d46' 4.36"N)
  Upper Right ( -97.4789168,  78.2772369) ( 97d28'44.10"W, 78d16'38.05"N)
  Lower Right ( -97.4789168,  54.7678790) ( 97d28'44.10"W, 54d46' 4.36"N)
  Center      (-132.4037879,  66.5225580) (132d24'13.64"W, 66d31'21.21"N)
  Band 1 Block=2973x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Gray
```

Comment: Run gdalinfo for both images and add extents and pixel sizes into your question.

Comment: Yeah, the corner coordinates and the pixel sizes are different! Is this the reason result in the different shape? and How do I deal with that? Or which one is more accurate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you show the images with some projection aware viewer, like QGIS, the images should look the same because the viewer knows how it should stretch the pixels to suit with the georeferencing. I guess that you are using some standard image viewer instead.

If you want to get similar pixel sizes run gdalwarp with the -tr option http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html.

> **-tr** *xres yres*:
>
> ```
> set output file resolution (in target georeferenced units)
> ```